# cannot sign in to asp.net mvc web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have following `Login` method (`POST`) to login for users

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);

            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");

            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });

            case SignInStatus.Failure:

            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");

                return View("MainDashboard", "Home", model);
        }
    }
```

But once I insert correct credentials (email and password) I cannot login , I'm getting

> The view 'MainDashboard' or its master was not found or no view engine
>   supports the searched locations. The following locations were
>   searched:

Error

I have `SignInManager` method as follows in same `AccountController` class

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private ProjectEntities db = new ProjectEntities();

    private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
    private ApplicationRoleManager _roleManager;

    public AccountController()
    {
    }            

    public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager, ApplicationRoleManager roleManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        RoleManager = roleManager;
        SignInManager = signInManager;
    }

    public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
        }
        private set 
        { 
            _signInManager = value; 
        }
    }

    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        ...
    }

    public ApplicationRoleManager RoleManager
    {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Its not the login that has the issue. The PasswordSignInAsync probably return Failure but then you return bad ViewResult

Comment: @tmg once I debug I can see `var result` become failer , whats the reason to this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading what you're trying to do correctly, you want to go to MainDashboard when you've signed in. If this is the case, then the logic of the login ActionResult should be like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    // Return to Login View if there is an invalid model submitted (with errors displayed)
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
    // Attempt to Login
    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
    switch (result)
    {
        // If Login is successful
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            // Go to the returnUrl if there is a returnUrl (used when User has been automatically signed out or has tried to hit an unauthorized page)
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
            {
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            } else
            {
               // Go to MainDashboard if there is no returnUrl and Login is successful (without referencing the LoginViewModel)
                return RedirectToAction("MainDashboard", "Home");
            }

        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            return View("Lockout");
        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
        default:
            // If Login has failed, and it's not due to a Lockout and not because the User has to Verify the Registration code on Registration
            // Return to the Login View with errors
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View(model);
    }
}
```

Also, obviously, make sure that there is a View and Controller action for MainDashboard in the Home controller. I may be reading what you want incorrectly, but if this is what you are trying to achieve, this is one way it could be done.